# How to retrieve data that is in a table? PostgreSQL, AngularJS1, Spring, Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my database I have last names and first names. I collect them in a array ; my variable lastAndFirstNameList contains: ex : `[name, first name] => ( ["WOOD", "Robin"])`

I then try to retrieve separately the last name and the first name with the variables lastname and firstname. I get the result « lastname undefined » and « firstname undefined ». I do not understand why! Could you help me please?

```
enter code here : //controller.js
            Employee.getFirstAndLastName().$promise.then(function(result) {
                var lastAndFirstNameList = result.list; 
                var lastname = lastAndFirstNameList.lastName;
                var firstname = lastAndFirstNameList.firstName;

                for(var k = 0; k < lastAndFirstNameList.length; k++)
                    {
                        console.log("lastname", lastname);
                        console.log("firstname", firstname);
                    }


                console.log("lastAndFirstNameList", lastAndFirstNameList);
        }
```

....

```
enter code here daoImpl.java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Object> getFirstAndLastName() {
    SQLQuery querySQL = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select last_name, first_name from employee");
    List<Object> firstAndLastNameList = querySQL.list();
    return firstAndLastNameList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does this give you?  I don't think that 'firstname' and 'lastname' will give you anything because the are not referenced correctly.

```
Employee.getFirstAndLastName().$promise.then(function(result) {
            var lastAndFirstNameList = result.list; 
            var lastname = lastAndFirstNameList.lastName;
            var firstname = lastAndFirstNameList.firstName;

            console.log("lastname ", lastname);
            console.log("firstname ", firstname);
            console.log("lastAndFirstNameList", lastAndFirstNameList);
}
```

Change the above reference variable to look like this:

```
var lastname = lastAndFirstNameList[0].lastName;
var firstname = lastAndFirstNameList[0].firstName;
```

That should give you the first value if passed correctly from the server.

Your loop should then look like this:

```
for(var k = 0; k < lastAndFirstNameList.length; k++){
    console.log("lastname", lastAndFirstNameList[k].lastName);
    console.log("firstname", firstname[k].firstName);
}
```